# Getting details on early termination of solvers invoked by PuLP

Tags: optimization, pulp

I can tell PuLP to limit the execution time of the MIP solver it invokes by run time and/or by allowable optimality gap.  When invoking CBC, this can look like:

```
status_C = prob.solve (PULP_CBC_CMD(maxSeconds=1, fracGap = 0.01))
```

or when invoking GLPK, like:

```
status_G = prob.solve(solver=pulp.GLPK(options=['--tmlim 60', '--mipgap 0.001']))
```

My question is:  how can I get more info about the nature of the early termination?

With CBC, if it hits the time limit, it returns `status_C` as 0 and the best feasible z (objective value) as `value(prob.objective)`.  But suppose the time limit isn't hit, but rather it terminates with optimality (possibly relaxed by `fracgap`).  Consider a case where the reported z value is 2201.2 with `fracgap = 0.00` and 2200.8 with `fracgap = 0.05`.  If I had done only the latter run by itself, I would have a solution of 2200.8 and the possibility that z* is 5% higher than that.  And yet (for extraneous reasons), I believe it probably had already tightened the LP bound much closer than that when it stopped.  To know if I'm right, I need to see what LP bound had been achieved.  Is that info available somewhere in the information provided back to PuLP?

With GLPK, the same kind of question applies but with an added complication.  Regardless of whether termination is due to time limit or gap tolerance, it returns `status_G` as 1, i.e., claiming an Optimal solution.  So now, in addition to looking for the progress of the LP bound at the time of termination, I'm also looking for extra information to tell me whether it was the time limit or the optimality tolerance that triggered termination.  If it was the time limit, I would of course want then to look at the optimization progress info (i.e., bounds) to see how close to optimality I may have gotten.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm sorry but pulp doesn't support this by default, as the various statuses are very solver specific. If you do want to do this stuff maybe you should run the solver manually yourself using the code from pulp as a template.

Comment: Just a follow up question. When the status is 0 (not solved), does the output objective value and variable value always correspond to the best feasible ones? Thanks @Stuart Mitchell.

Comment: Pretty late, but just in case anyone else is wondering:
Status 0 (not solved) means, as far as I have found out, just that - it is not solved. In fact, if you just create an empty problem without solving it or anything, it will have the status 0. So this status is no guarantee for anything. Though a status like "feasible, sub-optimal solution" would be awesome, I have not found this through the PULP interface.

Comment: With the `PULP_CBC_CMD` solver it is actually possible to retrieve the lower bound of the MIP, using a trick (examining the logs file). I've developped that answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75031855/13706904.